# What's the correct term for this network connection?

Tags: networking, terminology

What is the correct general term for the network connection on mobile devices that can connect to networks via telecoms links?

Question asked "my device is not connecting to my local web server here".

My response "Are you using Wifi or XXXX to to connect?"

Where XXXX is the network connection through the phone system - e.g. 3g, gprs, etc...

What is the general term encompassing term for XXXX please?

Comment: Why is this too localised?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for *mobile internet*.

As opposed to Wifi and [tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering).

Answer (score 1):

Generically, this often seems to be referred to as a "data" connection. Though, of course, that doesn't really make much sense as WiFi is also a "data" connection.

It really just differentiates between voice and data over the mobile wireless network.

Hence, many phones offer to turn off "data connections" when roaming as this is generally very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it *packet data* or *cellular*. The former seems more popular in Europe, whereas the latter term seems to be more common in the US, hence product names like iPad 'WiFi + Cellular'.